# How to improve python/tesseract Image to Text accuracy?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

How can I grab an image from a region and properly use tesseract to translate to text? I got this currently:

```
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(1341,182, 1778, 213))
tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(np.array(img), lang ='eng')
print (tesstr)
```

Issue is that it translates it incredibly wrong because the region it's getting the text from is in red with blue background, how can I improve its accuracy? Example of what it's trying to turn from image to text:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- *Issue is that it translates it incredibly wrong because the region it's getting the text from is in red with blue background, how can I improve its accuracy? *

You should know the [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). You need to try each of the suggested method listed. If you still can't achieve the desired result, you should look at the other methods:

- [Thresholding Operations using inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)
- [Changing Colorspaces](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)
- [Image segmentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

To get the desired result, you need to get the binary mask of the image. Both simple threshold, and adaptive-threshold won't work for the input image.

To get the binary mask

- 1. Up-sample and convert input image to the HSV color-space
- 2. Set lower and higher color boundaries.

Result:

[image]

The OCR output for 0.37 version will be:

```
Day 20204, 16:03:12: Your ‘Metal Triangle Foundation’
was destroved!
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("b.png")

# Up-sample
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to HSV color-space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get the binary mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 123]), np.array([179, 255, 255]))

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(msk)
print(txt)

# Display
cv2.imshow("msk", msk)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i was looking for, I knew mask could fix it but I couldn't udnerstand the right way to use it to get that effect. I have also found a work around by using:
red = [0,0,255]
    img[img != red] = 255

which turns the whole image white keeping only the red, which helped OCR aswell. your solution is far more universal though

Comment: Glad if I could help

Comment: If possible, could you take a look at my other question since you're clearly experienced with python you might know some alternatives:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655546/time-sleep-alternative-if-keyboard-is-pressed-alternative-need-to-be-able-to

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Tesseract API such that you are able to increase the DPI at which you examine the image to detect text. Higher the DPI, hihger the precision, till diminishing returns set in. More processing power is required. DPI should not exceed original image DPI.